# Php installation on windows server 2012 IIS 8

Tags: php, windows, iis, server

I am trying to host a php website on windows server 2012 with IIS 8. I have installed php using the WPI and have followed the enitre installation process given at :http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-php-on-windows-server-2012

But even after succesfull installation when I am trying to run info.php the following error is shown:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me out with solving this error?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess that you're missing to install "**FastCGI module**" or it is not activated in **Handler Mappings** for iis. That model is necessary for php.

Check this: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis

Well, this guide using Windows Server 2008, but it's the same concept as Windows Server 2012.

After installing try to open Internet Explorer as administrator (if you're using other account instead of the administrator account)